# Pass an object to a new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin

In Xamarin, how can I pass a user defined object (a Class that I have written) to a different activity?

The object I wish to pass is an item in a List called:

```
_mapLocationList[0]
```

The item is of type:

```
MapLocation
```

Here is my current code:

```
intent.PutExtra ("MapLocation", _mapLocationList[0]);
```

Can the above method be used to pass an object? If not, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of passing objects to an `Activity` is using `Intent`s. For this, you'll need your class to `implement` `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

This way, you would put your object in the `Intent` via the `putExtra("myobject", object)` method, and then in the other `Activity` recover it with `getSerializableExtra("myobject")`.

For example:

In the first `Activity`:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("my_class", your_maplocation_object);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your second `Activity`, you would do:

```
final Intent passedIntent = getIntent();
final MapLocation my_class = (MapLocation) passedIntent.getSerializableExtra("my_class");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more simple and very pleasant way : use Googe GSON library.

**Serialization in Activity A:**

```
intent.putExtra("mapLocExtra", new Gson().toJson(myMapLocationObject,MapLocation.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

***Deserialisation in Activity B: *

```
@Oncreate(...){

String mapLocJson= getIntent().getExtra("mapLocExtra").toString();
MapLocation mylocationObject= new Gson().fromJson(maplocJson,MapLocation.Class);

//do Stuff With mylocationObject
  }
```

More infos : https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Good idea but won't work with gson. Replace it with ServiceStack.Text or Json.NET serializer. He's using Xamarin... ;)